# Matplotlib/v-3.4.2 problem with latex preamble in matplotlibrc

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I have matplotlibrc file which contains following for latex preamble

```sh
text.latex.preamble : \usepackage{siunitx}, \usepackage{amsmath}, \boldmath
```

This definition used to work with matplotlib/v-3.03, but when I updated to  version-3.4.2, it stopped working. I checked the cached tex file that matplotlib created, I found that in version-3.4.2 it can not split preamble properly. I am  showing respectively lines from tex file bellow

**Version-3.0.3**

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\boldmath
```

**Version-3.4.2**

```
\usepackage{siunitx}, \usepackage{amsmath}, \boldmath
```

Can someone help me, the right way to define the preamble in  matplotlibrc file for new version? I know they have changed how to handle preamble but could not figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try without the colons in your matplotlibrc? The missing line breaks should not be a problem for latex

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks a lot. It worked. I think you mean comma

Comment: yes, you are totally correct, I meant comma. Was a bit a late yesterday when I wrote that :)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz do mind reply your answer in the "Answer" section so that I can accept your reply as an accepted answer. Thanks- Masrul

Comment: Can you write a self-answer? I'm not a matplotlib user, so can't test any code and this was just a wild guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, if I remove the commas from the preamble, it works for both the old and new versions.